# Laravel Mix + Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, laravel-mix

I use laravel mix (webpack) to compile my project. Trying to add slick carousel plugin but get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function` .

I use `.copy()` method in `webpack.mix.js` file to copy from node_modules directory to public directory:

```
.copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js', 'public/js')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css', 'public/css')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css', 'public/css')
```

All files successfully appeared in proper public directories and these files are seen in sources tab (in browser inspector).

After I plug slick styles, then jquery (tried several versions), then slick.js in html head. I even used cdn urls. 

It's all ok with slick if I do the same without laravel mix.

It doesn't work, I can't understand what's wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to change as below:

```
.copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/assets/js')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js', 'public/assets/js')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css', 'public/assets/css')
.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css', 'public/assets/css')
```

Reference: https://new.laravel.su/docs/5.4/mix

Answer (score -2):

First `npm install slick-carousel`

If you are using copy then

```
mix.copy('node_modules/slick-carousel/slick', 'public/assets/slick');
```

Or you can just manually copy-paste

In `.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```